# Reading string values under if/else commands

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im new to android so im gonna need a little help.
I created four activities in my app.
First activity is the MainActivity. 
I assigned a ListView in the first Activity.
From the listView you are redirected to the second activity with a string which says which item you clicked. It doesn't matter which item you selected, but you will be redirected to that second activity only. Only diffrence is that the values of the strings passed are different.
I used this code in the ListView's onItemClick function:

```
String item  = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                    i.putExtra("item_selected", item);
                    startActivity(i);
```

This code redirects me to the second activiy with the string without any problem.
In the second Activity there are two options "Launch Type 1" and "Launch type 2" inside a radioButton group and a button to perform the function.
So i used this code inside the button's onClick method to determine which Activity to go next:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String item = intent.getExtras().getString("item"); 
        RadioButton launch1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.launch1);

    //The problem code:..
    if(launch1.isChecked()){
        if(item=="ListView_Item1"){Intent launch1=new Intent(this, Launch_activity1.class); startActivity(launch1);}
    }
    else{
        if(item=="Item 1"){Intent launch2=new Intent(this, Launch_activity2.class); startActivity(launch2);}
    }
```

In Eclipse it shows that there are no errors in the code. But when I run it in the Emulator it starts off fine till it reaches the second activity.
When i click the button nothing is done and it does not redirect to any new page...
:(
Please help me in constructing the "if/else" statements in the button...and please do tell me if there are any better ways to achive the task...

Thanks in advance.
Waiting for replies....

Comment: Does your app crash? Logcat then please - and the solution might be the manifest: have you added the second activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you compare strings using `equals()` and not `==`.

```
if(item.equals("ListView_Item1"))
```

Using `==` you're comparing references and not content.

Use `Object#equals()` for checking if an object contains same data as another one and `==` for comparing if two references are referencing the same object.

Comment: @ShanzidSHaiham Welcome to SO :) I'm glad to have helped. You should mark the answer as correct (the little tick below the votes). Also I recommend you understand why equals() works and == does not. This will improve your understanding of how Java works :)

Comment: @ShanzidSHaiham You marked the other answer as correct, but anyway, no sweat :)

Comment: OOh! Sorry...
Better now?

Answer (score 0):

**use**  `equals()` for comparison of String or Objects in java !

**so your code should be :**

```
if(launch1.isChecked()){
        if(item.equals("ListView_Item1")){Intent launch1=new Intent(this, Launch_activity1.class); startActivity(launch1);}
    }
    else{
        if(item.equals("Item 1")){Intent launch2=new Intent(this, Launch_activity2.class); startActivity(launch2);}
    }
```